# Jenkins-Slave is Offline - Running Jenkins in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins

I am using the Kubernetes plugins to configure cloud for jenkins slave, the pod template is using `jenkins/inbound-agent` image. When I run a pipeline, it shows `jenkins-slave is offline`, running `kubectl -n jenkins get pods -A --watch` shows the pod ContainerCreating, Running, Terminating and then creates a new pod.

Here is the `service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-svc
  namespace: jenkins
  labels:
    app: jenkins-svc
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/path:   /
    prometheus.io/port:   '8080'
spec:
  selector:
    app: jenkins-deployment
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32100
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-jnlp
  namespace: jenkins
  labels:
    app: jenkins-jnlp
spec:
  selector:
    app: jenkins-deployment
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 50000
      targetPort: 50000
```

The kubernetes cloud details include:

1. Kubernetes URL: https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443
2. Kubernetes Namespace: jenkins
3. Credentials: Kubernetes Service Account: ran test (Connected to Kubernetes v1.25.4)
4. Jenkins URL: http://localhost:32100
5. Jenkins tunnel: localhost:50000

[image]

[image]

I tried changing the slave image, restarting jenkins, changed the service type but the pod keeps terminating, what is the possible solution to this?

Comment: Do you have logs from the agent service, or those pods' logs?

Comment: @ZacAnger I am new to Kubernetes, since the pods are crashing, how can I log them?

Comment: `kubectl logs [-n namespace] pod-name --previous`, assuming they're in a loop and not being cleaned up. If they are being cleaned up, you may need a real logging solution (like ELK, or a third-party solution like Datadog). If you're running k8s on a cloud provider they may have a solution for collecting all the logs automatically, or you could try checking /var/log/containers/ on the node that the pod was running on.

Comment: @ZacAnger The K8s is running on a VPS, although locally I am using docker-desktop for windows and running the command `kubectl -n jenkins logs --previous [pod-name]` throws `NotFound`

Comment: `[pod-name]` isn't literal, that needs to be the name of the restarting agent pod. If you did use the actual pod name and there are no logs on disk at /var/log/containers on the Node, I suggest reading [the guide to Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/) and figuring out a solution that works for you. Possibly the easiest _quick_ solution would be to run a sidecar that grabs logs from other pods, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61185832/5774952).